# Plot several graphs with R igraph

Tags: r, graph, igraph

I would like to draw two graphs `g1` and `g2` on the same plot with the `R` version of `igraph`. However, if I just apply the `plot` (or `plot.igraph`) function twice, I just get two separate plots. Is there a way to have both graphs drawn on the same plot?

Here's some minimal code:

```
library(igraph)
g1 <- barabasi.game(10)
g2 <- barabasi.game(5)
plot(g1)
plot(g2)
```

Edit: I want both graphs to be plotted in the same figure. So, one node from `g1` and another one from `g2` could very well overlap in this figure, if they hold close spatial positions in their respective graphs.

Comment: If you want to add the second graph to the same plot, just use the `add=TRUE` argument. After `plot(g1)`, try `plot(g2,add=TRUE)`.

Comment: Thanks nicola, that's it. I've also just found out I could call `par(new=TRUE)` between the `plot` calls.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
library(igraph)
g1 <- barabasi.game(10)
g2 <- barabasi.game(5)
plot(g1)
plot(g2, edge.color='black', vertex.color='green', add=T)
```

The main trick here is to use `add=TRUE` while plotting the second graph.

I have changed the color of edges and vertices of *g2* to be able to tell *g2* apart from *g1*.

Comment: nicola gave the same answer in the question comments. But thanks, anyway!

Answer (score 1):

we can use par(mfrow=c(1,2)), and write add=TRUE in 2nd plot.

```
          library(igraph)
          par(mfrow=c(1,2))
          g1 <- barabasi.game(10)
        g2 <- barabasi.game(5)
          plot(g1)
          plot(g2,add=TRUE)
```

Comment: Actually, I don't want the graphs as separate figures. I want them in the same figure, i.e. nodes and links could overlap.